# Convert HTML element and its image content to base64

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I want to 'capture' an element/image including the CSS style applied to them and out put them as one base64 image.

Should I be targeting the image or should I be targeting the `<figure>` element? As this element is actually where the CSS class resides (the CSS must target the `<figure>` element to work correctly).

I believe there are ways to directly convert an image into base64, however I am applying CSS to the image's parent `<figure>` element that isn't present on the source image so those methods I don't think apply here as they would ignore the CSS and HTML.

If it isn't possible simply with JS/jQuery as it is, is there a way to place this same setup (applied CSS and `<figure>` element) within an HTML5 canvas and capture it there?

```css
.image__container { width:300px; height:200px; overflow:hidden; }

#image { margin:0; padding:0; }

.toaster {
  -webkit-filter: contrast(1.5) brightness(.9);
  filter: contrast(1.5) brightness(.9)
}

.toaster::after {
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, #804e0f, #3b003b);
  background: radial-gradient(circle, #804e0f, #3b003b);
  mix-blend-mode: screen
}

.toaster:after,
.toaster:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none
}

.toaster {
  position: relative
}

.toaster img {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1
}

.toaster:before {
  z-index: 2
}

.toaster:after {
  z-index: 3
}
```

```html
CSS applied:
<section class="image__container">
  <figure id="image" class="toaster">
    <img src="http://d2d0b2rxqzh1q5.cloudfront.net/sv/3.65/dir/54b/image/54ba93e641021e29fbdc2eb3f7317266.jpg" width="300">
  </figure>
</section>

Original image:<br>
<img src="http://d2d0b2rxqzh1q5.cloudfront.net/sv/3.65/dir/54b/image/54ba93e641021e29fbdc2eb3f7317266.jpg" width="300">
```

Comment: use [**html2canvas**](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)

Comment: @ℊααnd I was looking into this I think a screenshot is limiting, so if the image itself is 1000px wide but is only 300px wide on the DOM. It will only output a 300px wide image. Not the real image size. Unless I've missed something?